# splitting column of a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apply

I have been trying to split the column of a dataframe, but I am getting an error:

> KeyError: ('LanguagesWorkedWith', 'occurred at index 0')

My code:

```
f = lambda x: len(Developers['LanguagesWorkedWith'].split(";"))-1
Developers['LanguagesWorkedWith'] = Developers.apply(f,axis=1)
```

The columns contain the following data in the below format:

[image]